# Flask JSON serializable error because of flask babel

Tags: python, json, unicode, flask

I am using https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/ extention for localization.

base form class

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from app import app
from flask.ext.wtf import Form

class BaseForm(Form):

    @property
    def error_list(self):
        _errors = []

        for fieldName, errorMessages in self.errors.iteritems():
            for err in errorMessages:
                _errors.append(err)

        return _errors
```

my form class

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import g

from wtforms import StringField, TextField, PasswordField # BooleanField
import wtforms.validators as validators
from flask.ext.babel import lazy_gettext as _
from flask.ext.babel import npgettext as _n

from app.base_forms import *

class PostForm(BaseForm):
    post_title    = StringField(_("Post Title"), [validators.Required(message=_("Post title is required")) ])
    post_content = StringField(_("Post Content"), [ validators.Required(message=_("Post content is required"))])
```

my view

```
...
viewJsonData["error_list"] = form.error_list
return jsonify(**viewJsonData)
```

It throws this error "TypeError: lu'Post content is required' is not JSON serializable".

when i remove localization from _("Post Title") to "Post Title" it work but when i use babel it does not work

I think it is about unicode. because i did this change _("Post Title").encode("utf-8") it works. But this solution is not effective. How can i solve the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is that your error message is a `_LazyString` object returned by `lazy_gettext`, not a string.  Normally, this wouldn't be an issue because displaying it in a template would call `str()` on it, causing it to evaluate the translation.  However, you are collecting the objects in `error_list`, and then passing them to `jsonify`, and json has no serializer for these objects.

You need to tell Flask's JSON serializer how to handle these objects.  Write a custom serializer then assign it to `app.json_encoder`.

```
from flask._compat import text_type
from flask.json import JSONEncoder as BaseEncoder
from speaklater import _LazyString

class JSONEncoder(BaseEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, _LazyString):
            return text_type(o)

        return BaseEncoder.default(self, o)

app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
```

Answer (score 0):

Change davidism's solution to

```
return str(o.encode('UTF-8'))
```

to work on Python 2 instead.